# Counting program unaligned address accesses on Sun OS, AIX

Tags: c++, aix, sunos

How to count program unaligned address accesses on Sun OS and AIX. Or how to measure time to system handling this exception on Sun OS and AIX ?

Comment: I believe that would be different on different hardware. What architecture?

Comment: Sun Os 5.10 on ultraspark T1
IBM AIX 6.1 on IBM processor

Comment: far too "real world" to be homework.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer but here's a useful link to [Developing and Tuning Applications on UltraSPARC T1 Chip Multithreading Systems](http://www.sun.com/blueprints/1205/819-5144.pdf).
I was kind of hoping there was a dedicated performance counter for such stuff.

There is also [dtrace](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/DTrace/dtrace+Provider) that might help here. All of this is for Solaris though, I have no idea if it's applicable to SunOS. No comment on AIX.
[Here](http://cmynhier.blogspot.com/)'s also a blog entry of a guy measuring aligned vs. unaligned Sparc memory access.